# F() messes with program

Tags: serial

I'm working on command-handler library and I have a big problem with `F()` function.
Example sketch for library uses quite a lot of RAM, because it has to print a lot of text over UART. As before, I've used `F()` to lower RAM usage. It worked on first!

Lib works with help of `strtok` function. Command fomar is:

> cmd1,..,paramN;..;cmdN,..,paramN

Commands are separated with `;` while command parameters(params) are separated with `,`
Library works without any problems, it returns memory address(`char*`) of any command and every param.

When I try to compare parameter/command with `strcmp` it works only if all commands are in uppercase.
Let's take `LED` command for example:
It works only with `Led`, `LED` or any case where is letter d in uppercase. `led` won't work, and it will say that command `le` doesn't exist. Yes, `le`, it won't print `led`. But, after `DURATION` command, it somehow start working.

Memory for serial buffer is dynamicly allocaed in object constructor, in global scope.
Why? All those problems are because `F()`. Can someone explain why? Here's the code and screenshot of serial monitor.

```
void execCmd(const char *set)
{
char *cmdParam = CMDHandler.find(set, CMD_PARAM);

if (!strcmp(cmdParam, "LED"))
{
    // ONE WAY TO CHECK IF COMMAND HAS PARAM(S) - BEFORE GETTING PARAM(S) == BETTER WAY
    if (!CMDHandler.count(CMDHandler.getNext(CMD_PARAM), CMD_PARAM))
    {       
        Serial.print(F("->> Command LED: Current LED status is "));
        Serial.println(digitalRead(LED_PIN));
        return;     
    }

    cmdParam = CMDHandler.find(nullptr, CMD_PARAM);
    LEDStatus = 0;
    uint8_t status = atoi(cmdParam);

    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, status);
    Serial.print(F("->> Command led: LED Status is "));
    Serial.println(status, DEC);
}
else if (!strcmp(cmdParam, "LOOP"))
{
    cmdParam = CMDHandler.find(nullptr, CMD_PARAM);

    // SECOND WAY TO CHECK IF COMMAND HAS PARAM(S) - AFTER GETTING EVERY PARAM
    if (cmdParam == nullptr)
    {
        Serial.println(F("->> Command LOOP: Expected one parameter!"));
        return;
    }   

    uint8_t status = atoi(cmdParam);
    if (status)
    {
        LEDStatus = 2;
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        Serial.println(F("->> Command LOOP: LED Blink Loop is on!"));
        delay(blinkDuration);
    }
    else
    {
        LEDStatus = 0;
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        Serial.println(F("->> Command LOOP: LED Blink Loop is off!"));          
    }   
}
else if (!strcmp(cmdParam, "DURATION"))
{
    if (!CMDHandler.count(CMDHandler.getNext(CMD_PARAM), CMD_PARAM))
    {
        Serial.print(F("->> Command DURATION: Current blink duration is "));
        Serial.print(blinkDuration, DEC);
        Serial.println("ms");
        return;     
    }

    cmdParam = CMDHandler.find(nullptr, CMD_PARAM);
    blinkDuration = atoi(cmdParam);

    Serial.print(F("->> Command DURATION: New blink duration is "));    
    Serial.print(blinkDuration, DEC);
    Serial.println("ms!");  
}
else if (!strcmp(cmdParam, "HELP"))
{
    Serial.println(F("------ HELP ------\n-> LED [0/1] - Turns off/on LED on pin 13\n-> LOOP [0/1] - Stops/starts blink loop with LED on pin 13\n-> DURATION [X] - Changes duration of LED loop blink. Recommended values is 50-500ms\n"));
}
else
{
    Serial.print(F("->> Command "));
    Serial.print(cmdParam);
    Serial.println(F(" does not exist!"));
}
```

}

```
char *CMDHand::find(const char *input, uint8_t const type)
{
    char *found = nullptr;
    char separator = delimiter[type];

    if (input != nullptr) // FIRST CALL
    {
        constrain[type] = input + strlen(input) - 1;
        next[type] = input;
    }
    else if (next[type] > constrain[type]) return (nullptr);

    found = strtok(next[type], &separator); // FOR SOME REASON IT DOES NOT WORK IF I PUT &delimiter[type] INSTEAD OF &separator
    last[type] = next[type];
    next[type] += strlen(found) + 1;

    return (found);
}
```

[image: Screenshot of serail monitor]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare with `F()` macro encased strings you have to use special forms of the string functions that are suffixed with `_P`.  You also need to cast the string literals to the right type (`PGM_P`).

To do a case-insensitive comparison you should use `strcasecmp` instead of `strcmp`.

To put those together you end up with:

```
if (strcasecmp_P(cmdParam, (PGM_P)F("help")) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

---

There is a problem here:

```
found = strtok(next[type], &separator)
```

`strtok` takes a C string as a list of separators (must be NULL terminated). You're passing it the address of a single character. There may or may not (probably not) be a NULL in the next byte in memory, but everything else up to the first NULL found in memory will be taken as delimiter characters.

Comment: Are all these specific '_P' functions documented somewhere? I know a few but not all of them like strcasecmp_P.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers https://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html

Comment: No, I've used `F()` for `Serial.print()` and `Serial.println()`, not for ˙strcmp()`. Why I should used it in `strcmp()` then?.

Comment: For the same reasons as in Serial.print. To save RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much (I already upvoted your answer).

Comment: @Majenko sorry, but no. It doesn't work as it should. `led` doesn't work because somehow `led` becomes `le`(I know because it says `command le doesn't exist`). `LED` works. I don't know why letter `d`(lowercase d) causes all those problems. No matter what command I type, if it has `d`, it will cause problem. Without `F()` in `Serial.print/ln` all works fine. Why?

Comment: @SilvioCro Then there is something strange happening in the mysterious `CMDHandler` class's `find` method. If your string is not parsing correctly you should look at the parser, not the comparison structure.

Comment: @Majenko added `find` method. Code works fine when I don't use `F()`, even I tried as C++ program. Seems like `F()` overrides part of the buffer for the Serial, since if I print text using `next` from `find` method, I can see part of the text that I didn't write.

Comment: You have a critical mistake in your find method. See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works.